# FullscreenDialog screen not covering bottomnavigationbar

Tags: flutter

How do I create a fullscreenDialog that covers my bottomnavigationbar?

My mainscreen looks like this, where I have a bottomnavigationbar which navigates to three different screens.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        children: [new HomeTab(), new PresentationsTab(), new TestTab()],
        controller: _pageController,
        onPageChanged: pageChanged,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _page,
        onTap: tapBottomNav,
        items: [
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.home),
            title: new Text('Home'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.pregnant_woman),
            title: new Text('Presentation'),
          ),
          new BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.pregnant_woman),
            title: new Text('Presentation'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

And somewhere I have a screen which navigates to another screen with the fullscreenDialog flag set to true like this.

```
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => new AddAudio(),
      fullscreenDialog: true,
    ),
  );
```

On my appbar I can see that the flag actually works because my backbutton arrow will become an x, but my bottomnavigationbar will still be visible, how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer for you on my post: [Flutter MaterialPageRoute as fullscreenDialog appears underneath BottomNavigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231337/flutter-materialpageroute-as-fullscreendialog-appears-underneath-bottomnavigatio/63282662#63282662)

But, to recap for you:
I assume you are presenting your modal from a page which is itself a `Scaffold`? In which case you have nested `Scaffold` objects, and this is where the problem lies. To ensure your modal appears above the `BottomNavigationBar` you need to include that widget in the child `Scaffold` and not in the root one.

This seems like an utter pain in the arse, and not a great solution with loads of boilerplate and code duplication; but it isn't. You just need to build a custom composition widget for `BottomNavigationBar` and then use `ChangeNotifier` with a state class to manage state. I've explained it in the post I reference above, and it is probably better to read the answer there so you understand the context.

Comment: Honestly the code works properly now. I dont think the scaffolds are nested here since I'm pushing a new (modal) screen on top. I checked your problem out and I'm a little bit confused with the given snippets.

Answer (score -2):

That is probably the expected behavior, you should push a `PageRoute` (with a `PageRouteBuilder`) and use a custom transition to have the bottom to top slide animation.

Comment: How does this help? I don't really need to change my animations. I need my screen/view to fill the whole screen and cover my bottom navigation tabs.

Comment: I'm not sure and I can't test it right now but I suspect the MaterialPageRoute with the  fullscreenDialog flag is supposed to act like that, while a PageRoute does not.

Comment: I tried with modalroute and pageroute but it does not seem to work. I'm guessing it has something to do with my navigator, as modalroute covers the whole navigator.

Comment: @Syph - did you ever find a solution to this? I have a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231337/flutter-materialpageroute-as-fullscreendialog-appears-underneath-bottomnavigatio