# Flutter MaterialPageRoute as fullscreenDialog appears underneath BottomNavigationBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

There's a similar unanswered question here: [FullscreenDialog screen not covering bottomnavigationbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557631/fullscreendialog-screen-not-covering-bottomnavigationbar)
but I want to provide more context, to see if that helps find a solution.
We'll start at the top with my `main.dart`, I am building a `MaterialApp` that builds a custom `DynamicApp`. Here's the important stuff:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var _rootScreenSwitcher = RootScreenSwitcher(key: switcherKey);

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.green,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return DynamicApp(
          navigator: locator<NavigationService>().navigatorKey,
          child: child,
          switcher: _rootScreenSwitcher,
        );
      },
      navigatorKey: locator<NavigationService>().navigatorKey,
      onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
        switch (routeSettings.name) {
          case SettingsNavigator.routeName:
            return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SettingsNavigator(),
                fullscreenDialog: true);
          default:
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SettingsNavigator());
        }
      },
      home: _rootScreenSwitcher,
    );
  }
```

My `DynamicApp` sets up the root `Scaffold` like so:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: NavigationDrawer(
        selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
        drawerItems: widget.drawerItems,
        headerView: Container(
          child: Text('Drawer Header'),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
        ),
        onNavigationItemSelect: (index) {
          onTapped(index);
          return true; // true means that drawer must close and false is Vice versa
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        onTap: (index) {
          onTapped(index);
        },
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        items: bottomNavBarItems,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
      ),
      body: widget.child,
    );
  }
```

The child of the `DynamicApp` is a widget called `RootScreenSwitcher` which is an `IndexedStack` and controls the switching of screens from my `BottomNavigationBar` and also when items are selected in the `Drawer`. Here's the `RootScreenSwitcher`:

```
class RootScreenSwitcherState extends State<RootScreenSwitcher> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  int get currentIndex => _currentIndex;
  set currentIndex(index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        top: false,
        child: IndexedStack(
          index: _currentIndex,
          children: menuItems.map<Widget>((MenuItem item) {
            return item.widget;
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void switchScreen(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }
}
```

Each of the main section of the app has its own `Navigator` and root screen. This all works fine, and I'm happy with the overall navigation structure. Each root screen has its own `AppBar` but the global `Drawer` and `BottomNavigationBar` are handled in the `DynamicApp` so I don't have to keep setting them in the other `Scaffold` screens.

So, then it came to start to introduce other sections of the app that are not serviced by the bottom tab bar, and can be presented from the `Drawer` or from other action buttons. Each of these new sections would have to be modal `fullscreenDialog` screens so they slide up from the bottom, but have their own navigation and scaffold.

My issue is that when I navigate to my `SettingsNavigator` screen it slides up from behind the `BottomNavigationBar`, and not on top of everything. Here's the `onGenerateRoute` method of the `MaterialApp`:

```
onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
        switch (routeSettings.name) {
          case SettingsNavigator.routeName:
            return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => SettingsNavigator(),
                fullscreenDialog: true);
          default:
            return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SettingsNavigator());
        }
      }
```

I'm new to Flutter and don't quite understand how routing works with contexts, so I am wondering whether the context of the screen that calls the `navigateTo` method of the `Navigator` becomes the main build context, and is therefore not on top of the widget tree?

gif here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwgzo0q28cqk61p/FlutteRModalProb.gif?dl=0

Here's the tree structure that shows that the Scaffold for the Settings screen has been placed inside the `DynamicApp` `Scaffold`. The modal needs to sit above `DynamicApp`.
[image]

Can anyone shed some light on this?

UPDATE: I have tried creating and sharing a unique `ScaffoldState` key for the tab bar screens, and then the Settings page has a different key. It made no difference. I wonder now if it is the `BuildContext` having the same parent.

UPDATE UPDATE:
I had a breakthrough last night which has made me realise that it just isn't going to be possible to use embedded Scaffolds in the way I have them at the moment. The problem is that i have a root scaffold called `DynamicApp` which persists my `Drawer` and `BottomNavigationBar`, but loading in other `Scaffold` pages into the body means the modals are slotting into that body and behind the `BottomNavigationBar`. To solve the problem you have to subclass `BottomNavigationBar` and reference it in every `Scaffold`; which means encapsulating all of the business logic so it uses `ChangeNotifier` to change state when the nav is interacted with. Basically, Flutter forces a *separation of concerns* on your architecture, which I guess is a good thing. I'll compose a better answer when I've done all the extra work.

Comment: in your default: return try making it fullscreenDialog: true)

Comment: It is being set to fullscreenDialog = true. It behaves as a modal and has the default close button, it just appears under the tab bar.

Comment: Ahh, wait ... I see what you mean ...

Comment: but the modal works apart from the nav bar being on top so I don’t think the switch is falling through.

Comment: The issue I can see here now is that I have nested Scaffold's. I can't see how to do this without nesting them though. I want to have a common bottom tab bar and drawer, and then manage the appbar per screen.

Comment: sorry took long i'm working on answer should be live in a few

Answer (score 0):

After many hours tearing my hair out trying to pass `ScaffoldState` keys around, and `Navigators` the answer was to build the `BottomNavigationBar` into every `Scaffold`. But to do this I've had to change how my architecture works ... for the better! I now have a `BottomNavigationBar` and `RootScreenSwitcher` that listens for updates from an `AppState` `ChangeNotifier` and rebuilds itself when the page index changes. So, I only have to change state in one place for the app to adapt automatically. This is the `AppState` class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppState extends ChangeNotifier {

  int _pageIndex = 0;
  int get pageIndex {
    return _pageIndex;
  }

  set setpageIndex(int index) {
    _pageIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

and this is my custom `BottomNavigationBar` called `AppBottomNavigationBar`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class AppBottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  AppBottomNavigationBar({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _AppBottomNavigationBarState createState() => _AppBottomNavigationBarState();
}

class _AppBottomNavigationBarState extends State<AppBottomNavigationBar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var state = Provider.of<AppState>(
      context,
    );
    int currentIndex = state.pageIndex;
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      currentIndex: currentIndex ?? 0,
      items: bottomNavBarItems,
      showUnselectedLabels: false,
      onTap: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          state.setpageIndex = index;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

So, now in my other `Scaffold` pages I only need to include this line to make sure the `BottomNavigationBar is in the` Scaffold`:

```
bottomNavigationBar: AppBottomNavigationBar(),
```

Which means absolute minimal boilerplate.
I changed the name of the `DynamicApp` class to `AppRootScaffold` and this now contains a `Scaffold`, `Drawer`, and then set the body of the `Scaffold` as the `RootScreenSwitcher`:

```
class RootScreenSwitcher extends StatelessWidget {
  RootScreenSwitcher({Key key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var state = Provider.of<AppState>(
      context,
    );
    int currentIndex = state.pageIndex;
    return SafeArea(
      top: false,
      child: IndexedStack(
        index: currentIndex ?? 0,
        children: menuItems.map<Widget>((MenuItem item) {
          return item.widget;
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I still have a lot to do to streamline this architecture, but it is definitely the better way to go.

UPDATE:
Can you spot the problem with the new `Scaffold` architecture?
[image]
This is still not great. Ironically, I need the `BottomNavigationBar` back in the root `Scaffold` for this to work as expected. But then the modals wont appear over the top of the bar again.